# annotate optional return type

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I am having issue in assigning the return type of below method to a variable of integer type in advanced compilation mode of google closure. Also i don't want to use getter/setter method as a replacement for below code.

```
/**
 * Sets the idNum of this shape.
 * @override
 * @param {...number} id The number to set idNum, optional parameter.
 * @returns {number} Returns idNum if nothing is passed in.
 */


app.Shape.prototype.idNum = function(id) {
if(goog.isDef(id)) {
        this._idNum = id;
    } else {
        return this._idNum;
    }
};
```

How should i update my annotation for 
@returns 
so that above method may or may not return number depending on the parameter passed.

Comment: "Also i don't want to use getter/setter method as a replacement for below code." May I ask why? That strikes me as exactly what you *should* do here. Since the caller always knows whether or not he or she wants to get or set based upon the presence of the parameter, the caller does not have any complexity abstracted away by combining two distinct behaviors into the same function.

Comment: its because, there are plenty of such methods in my library, i want to reduce the size of javascript code, that will be compiled and downloaded finally.

Comment: there is no point to trying to optimize by hand, what the compiler will optimize for you later. in this case you're just writing ugly code instead of making anything better

Answer (score 2):

It's a little strange to have the same function be both a getter and a setter, depending on how it's called. But anyway: Use an `=` for the optional parameter: `{number=}`. For your "optional return" you can write the return type as `{number|undefined}` because if you don't hit a 'return' statement, the function will just return undefined. See [Annotating JavaScript for the Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) for more.

Answer (score 0):

The Closure Compiler doesn't support having more than one signature for a function, you basically want:

```
/** @type {(function(number):undefined)|(function():number)} */
```

Currently, the compiler merges this into "Function".  More specifically, you want to say not that it is either of those types but both of those types and there is nothing like that now.

While you can manually merge the function signature to be:

```
/** 
 * @param {number=} opt_id
 * @return {number|undefined}
 */
```

This means the return type is always "number|undefined" not the return type is "undefined" when the parameter is specified and "number" otherwise when leaves consumers having to "narrow" the results to either "number" or "undefined" after every call which is an awkward api.

Answer (score 0):

While having a function be both a getter and a setter is not strange in many scenarios, you are fighting against what Closure Compiler is trying to do for you.

JavaScript is loosely-typed, meaning anything can be "this type OR that type OR another type OR ...." with no limit on the size of this list.

CC is trying to help by enforcing strong-types. The strongest possible typing insists that a given variable is "this one type only", but this rigidity is often a pain (not allowing a NULL or UNDEFINED value in particular). CC relaxes this by allowing "a few types only" that you must spell out. However, you should be aware that this relaxation is one small step backwards, towards the wild west of loose-typing.

If you are using CC to improve your code, then listen to what it is trying to tell you. If you find yourself fighting to find the right annotation for something, or your lists of types are growing, then maybe you need to reconsider your use of CC and strong-typing in the first place.

Personally, I prefer strong-typing and simpler, shorter, clearer code. In your example, CC is trying to help by obliquely hinting at the down-side of combining getter and setter functionality.